# Split string with inconsistent delimiter

Tags: vba, excel, split

I have a column that contains city, state and zip code.

```
CITY_STATE_ZIP                                           
--------------------------------------------------
Monroe, IN 46711
South Bend, IN 46615
Alexandria, IN 46001
```

I wants the three words 'CITY_STATE_ZIP' to be split into different columns.

```
      CITY STATE      ZIP
---------- ---------- --------------------
    Monroe IN         46711
South Bend IN         46615
Alexandria IN         46001
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it as follows, if you want to use VBA.

```
Sub splitIntoCols()

    Dim oRange As Excel.Range
    Dim oCell As Excel.Range
    Dim vValue As Variant
    Dim sCity As String
    Dim sState As String
    Dim sZipCode As String

    Set oRange = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A3:A100")

    For Each oCell In oRange

        'Takes the whole value
        vValue = oCell.Value

        'Retrieve the City name (with or without spaces)
        sCity = Left(vValue, InStr(vValue, ",") - 1)

        'Remove the city name from the array
        vValue = Trim(Mid(vValue, InStr(vValue, ",") + 1))

        'Split the value by spaces
        vValue = split(vValue, " ")

        sState = vValue(0)
        sZipCode = vValue(1)

    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a menu item "Text to Columns" that launches a wizard to do this.  (If you need VBA code, you can turn on the macro recorder and see what it generates.)

Comment: Thank you but i need a VBA code. Can you guys put code please? I tried your instruction but it's very basic. I need an advanced code. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing your cells are in column A:

```
Sub a()
Dim r As Range
Set r = Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").End(xlDown))
For Each k In r
   Cells(k.Row, 4) = Mid(k, Len(k) - 5)
   Cells(k.Row, 3) = Mid(k, Len(k) - 7, 2)
   Cells(k.Row, 2) = Mid(k, 1, Len(k) - 10)
Next k
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a litte unsure if you're trying to do this in a macro or spreadsheet.  The following will work in a spreadsheet and can be modified for a macro.

Assuming your column of data in column D, and this example is spliting a string in D4.

Field D5 has the function

```
=LEFT(D4, FIND(",",D4)-1)
```

Field D6 has the function

```
=LEFT(MID(D4,FIND(",",D4)+2,LEN(D4)),FIND(" ", MID(D4,FIND(",",D4)+2,LEN(D4))))
```

Field D7 has

```
=RIGHT(MID(D4,FIND(",",D4)+2,LEN(D4)),LEN(MID(D4,FIND(",",D4)+2,LEN(D4))) -FIND(" ", MID(D4,FIND(",",D4)+2,LEN(D4))))
```